# Change Header on Masterpage depening on what page is being display

Tags: .net

Ok, I have read some really good suggestions.  I have a car dealership website that has a  page for each manufacturer.  I have created a header for each manufacturer which I have currently in an html file.  So when I click on Ford, It will call the masterpage to get the data and I want to create a conditional statement that tells the masterpage to display the Ford page header.  Just the same, if I click on Chevy, I want the masterpage to display the Chevy header.

It has been a while since I have created a loop like this and I need some help with the code.

When the pages were in html. my code looked like...

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" topmargin="0"  onLoad="StartRotation(); type(); return true" align="center">

  <!-- #include file="header-Toyota.html" -->
  <!-- #include file="body.html" -->
  <!-- #include file="footer.html" -->

</body>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Layla, I think it'd be a  good idea to use [WebControls](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/controls/default.aspx). Learn how to use them, and then just add the WebControl to your MasterPage's header. Insert the Business Rule inside the MasterPage's Load event to decide what WebControl or what Content within your WebControl is going to be load. This is not too hard. If you any more specific questions you can contact me to Guide you through it or to give you more information on the matter.

Good luck!

Comment: Alrighty then, I have a general idea on how to do this but need some extra hand holding.  Can you help Hanlet?

Comment: @Layla Of course. You could ask directly in here or add me in GTalk or write an email. Good luck!

Comment: I use VWD to help build my websites.  So, what I was thinking is putting each of the page's header images into a table on the master page and making them all visible="false".  Then in .cs MasterPage, On Page_Load I need to build the conditional statement that says (here is where I am having the problem) if destination page = Toyota then Toyota Table Visible and all of the other tables are not.  And then duplicate that for the other Manufacturers. 

What do you think?  How can I email you directly?

Comment: I just read the FAQ and I don't see anywhere that I cannot share my email address here, so here you go: hanlet.escano@gmail.com You could either add me to GTalk or write emails.